# Youtube API upload gets aborted

Tags: c#, .net, youtube-api

I'm trying to Upload a Video to Youtube using C#.
It does work for very small videos, but for bigger ones the upload gets aborted everytime.
That's my code:

```
public void VideoAPIUpload(Video video)
{
    YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("example app", "AI39si4mUhdQfat8Dsd54qDjKSXYYnYxTaIX5PNurJetTvcAPagRvbSSR2o5xDH_obI4TEDvNieOhHEUmD9_cw0qPD51zj_wpA", "Minecraftexpertenerten@gmail.com", "mutter123") { Timeout = -1 }; ;
    settings.Maximum = -1;
    YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
    Google.YouTube.Video newVideo = new Google.YouTube.Video();
    newVideo.Title = video.title;
    newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Autos", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
    newVideo.Keywords = video.tags;
    newVideo.Description = video.description;
    newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;
    newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("mydevtag, anotherdevtag",
      YouTubeNameTable.DeveloperTagSchema));

    // alternatively, you could just specify a descriptive string
    // newVideo.YouTubeEntry.setYouTubeExtension("location", "Mountain View, CA");

    newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource("funny_video.flv",
      "video/x-flv");
    Google.YouTube.Video createdVideo = request.Upload(newVideo);
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that YouTube doesn't want your larger video.  Have you tried this, to increase your limit?  http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=71673

Comment: How large are the "bigger" ones that you're trying to upload?

Comment: No, the video is about 4 minutes long :S

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15780318/551744

Answer (score 0):

There's a default client-side timeout imposed by the .NET GData library, and when uploading a particularly large video or when using a slow connection, it's fairly easy to trigger it.

Please see http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/issues/list?can=1&q=timeout for many examples of similar reports, as well as the relevant code changes that will increase the timeout.